# Facebook app iframe won't attempt to load when logged in as page

Tags: post, facebook-iframe, facebook-page

I have an [app](https://apps.facebook.com/authorapp) that shows up as an iframe on a Page. ([Here's an example.](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Test-Author-2/168495943220078?sk=app_191387770912394))

- If you view the app tab as a Facebook user, whether you have the app installed or not, everything works correctly.
- If you view the app tab as a Facebook Page that **has not** installed the app, everything works correctly.
- If you view the app tab as a Facebook Page that **has** installed the app, nothing displays. In fact, when sniffing the HTTP headers, it looks like *no attempt is ever made to load the app URL*.

Any idea what needs to happen on the Facebook side of the equation in order to have the tab at least make an attempt to load the app's page?

Thanks!

Comment: More details: If you are logged in as a Page and uninstall the app, everything works correctly. The issue occurs only if you currently have the app installed.

Comment: I am seeing this issue too with an app (voted up).

Comment: This is a bug/desired-behavior of Profile Tab applications while using Facebook as page, status of this can be tracked on http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/141770462584785

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now a desired behavior, once you trying to visit Application Tab by being logged in as Page you'll be prompted to use Facebook as regular user:

> To access this page, you'll need to switch from using Facebook as your page to using Facebook as yourself.

BTW, this was described in bug [Blank app page](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/141770462584785) which is marked as fixed (and the described behavior sadly was a way to fix this)...